# Sync short caption (for a figure list) with part of the long caption

Tags: captions

I would like to dynamically copy the first sentence of my long caption into the short caption for generating the figure list. Whenever I make changes to the long caption, the short caption updates accordingly.

To be more precise, I'd like to some sort of setter-getter mechanism for all the captions of my figures.

`\caption[text_A_getter]{text_A_setter. text_B.}`

I could save textA to a file but find it difficult to maintain for a large number of figures simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this really is the best idea and that practical, but you could use a command and redefine it if needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\firstsent}{}
\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\renewcommand{\firstsent}{This is the first sentence.}
\caption[\firstsent]{\firstsent{} And here comes the rest of the long caption.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\renewcommand{\firstsent}{This caption gets a different first sentence.}
\caption[\firstsent]{\firstsent{} Remaining text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```